# Need the background to change when the mouse goes over the selected tab. How?

Tags: html, css

I want the Tags tab to have the same background as the Search tab when the mouse is over it, how do I do this?

I have the search tab already with a background as a default but when going to click on Tags how can I get the same background that is on Search to appear behind Tags?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>

<link href="arg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>


<div class="tab-item tab-selected" id="search-box">
Search
</div>
<div class="tab-item" id="tag-box">
Tags
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.tab-item {
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
font: 14px helvetica;
color: #000;
height: 20px;
float: left;
margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
position: relative;
width: 75px;
}

.tab-mouseover {
background: #bdbdbd;
}

.tab-selected {
background: #c0c0c0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `hover` css pseudoclass

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/7FvR5/

```
tab-item:hover {     background: #c0c0c0;  }
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Btw Im not the best at CSS.. how do I align both tabs next to eachother in css in the center? When i change the alignment to center its puts one tab on top of another

Comment: No problem. use `margin: 0 auto;` along with a specified `width.` http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/7FvR5/1/

Answer (score 3):

unable to add a comment due to my low rep, but i wanted to say that right now what you're doing is just creating a class named "tab-mouseover" which has a background of #bdbdbd.  If you apply this class to an element, it will just have a background of #bdbdbd.  It doesn't actually mean it will change colors when you mouse over.

Please note that **names** of classes can be anything.  However, in order to achieve the effect you want, you need to do what mrtsherman mentioned (except change the background color to: "#bdbdbd").